# PHP: Check if objects contain a value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have been searching here for an answer but I can't find what I need.

I m using codeigniter 3 but my problem is with php syntax / logic.

The situation :

I have 3 arrays containing the correct values. I need to compare these array with an other array.

```
$t = $daxArt -> result ();

    foreach ($CSS -> result() as $object ){     

        if ($object -> PAYMETHOD == "CASH" ){

            array_push ($Cash , $object );      

        }
        if ($object -> PAYMETHOD == "EC"  ){

            array_push ($EC , $object );    

        }   
        if ($object -> PAYMETHOD == "POSCOM" ){     

            array_push ($POSCOM , $object );
        }   
    }
```

Now I have to do something like this :

```
if ($Cash contains one of the value $daxArt){   
  <---- here is my problem - add to new array.
}
```

I tried with in_array but it doesn't work.

thank you !

Comment: What is your input? What is in `$daxArt`, `$CSS`, `$Cash` etc?

Comment: You mean the `in_array()` or `array_keys()` function?

Comment: `I tried with in_array but it doesn't work.` Tried what? You've only posted half the code needed to debug this

Comment: $t  //  array(24) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (1) { ["articleNumero"]=> string(7) "2010102" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#23 (1) { ["articleNumero"]=> string(4) "9999" } $t contains only some article number. $Cash $EC and $POSCOM have the same datastructure : //array(182) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#49 (5) { ["ARTICLENO"]=> string(3) "100" ["DESCRIPTION"]=> string(28) "XXXXX" ["REVENUE"]=> string(5) "10501" ..... Now what i want to do is to create an 3 array 
 and had the article when ARTICLENO equals articleNumero.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $daxArt, $CSS, $Cash etc all contain similar objects you could do the following.

After your initial processing you could use **array_intersect()** this will compare two arrays and return a single array of only values that existed in both.

So for example you could do the following:

```
<?php

$t = $daxArt->result();

foreach($css->result() as $object){
    if ($object->PAYMETHOD == "CASH"){
        array_push ($Cash , $object);      
    }

    if ($object->PAYMETHOD == "EC"){
        array_push ($EC , $object);    
    }   

    if ($object->PAYMETHOD == "POSCOM"){     
        array_push ($POSCOM , $object);
    } 
}

//Get values for each of the $Cash, $EC, $POSCOM that are in $daxArt->result();
$cashDaxArt = array_intersect($Cash, $t);
$ecDaxArt = array_intersect($EC, $t);
$poscomDaxArt = array_intersect($POSCOM, $t);

//Check if cash contained values returned by $daxArt->result();
if(!empty($cashDaxArt)){
    //$Cash contained a value in $daxArt->result()!
}

?>
```

This can be shortend, by moving array intersect into the if statements but i though breaking the two out would be easier to read.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you for you answer. $Cash, $EC, $POSCOM have the same data structure  it looks like this : //array(182) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#49 (5) { ["ARTICLENO"]=> string(3) "100" ["DESCRIPTION"]=> string(28) "xxxxx" ["REVENUE"]=> string(5) "10501" etc..... And $t looks like this and contains only number : //array(24) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (1) { ["articleNumero"]=> string(7) "2010102" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#23 (1) { ["articleNumero"]=> string(4) "9999" }etc..... Now i want to compare articleNumero and ARTICLENO for $Cash, $EC and $POSCOM. if they equals, add the article in a new Array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$CASH = $EC = $POSCOM = array();
foreach ($CSS -> result() as $object ){     
        if (in_array( $object->PAYMETHOD, array("CASH","EC","POSCOM"))
        {
              ${$object->PAYMETHOD}[] = $object;
        }
}
```